# How to update MySQL query with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am new in php. I have this array and I want to update my table.

My table containing 1 to 36 column.

This `$test` array containing keys as my table column name i.e.(`[0][2][4]`) and values as my table data i.e.(`1`,`22`,`1`) which I want to update table row.

```
$test=  Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 22
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 0.25
    [6] => 0.25
    [8] => 1.25
    [9] => 0.25
    [11] => 1
    [29] => 0.25
    [30] => 0.25
    [32] => 0.25
    [33] => 0.25
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code to make the query for simple SQL statements

```
    <?php
$test=  Array
(
    0 => 1,
    2 => 22,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 0.25,
    6 => 0.25,
    8 => 1.25,
    9 => 0.25,
    11 => 1,
    29 => 0.25,
    30 => 0.25,
    32 => 0.25,
    33 => 0.25
);
$query = 'update table_name set ';
$counter = 0;
foreach ($test as $columns => $value) {
  $query .= "{$columns} = {$value}";
  $counter++;
  if($counter!=count($test))
  $query.=', ';
}
$query .=' where some_column = some_value';
echo $query;
 ?>
```

**For Prepared statements you can do something like this**

```
    <?php
$test=  Array
(
    0 => 1,
    2 => 22,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 0.25,
    6 => 0.25,
    8 => 1.25,
    9 => 0.25,
    11 => 1,
    29 => 0.25,
    30 => 0.25,
    32 => 0.25,
    33 => 0.25
);

$query = '$sql = UPDATE Applicant SET ';
$counter = 0;
foreach ($test as $columns => $value) {
  $query .= "{$columns} = ?";
  $counter++;
  if($counter!=count($test))
  $query.=', ';
}
$query .=' where some_column = ?';
echo $query;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiiiiiii', $test[0],$test[2],$test[4],$test[5],$test[6],$test[8],$test[9],$test[11],$test[29],$test[30],$test[32],$test[33],$condition);
$stmt->execute();
 ?>
```

For efficiency and safety I suggest you to use prepared statements. Thanks

Comment: @user3783243. I am also updating query for parameterized queries

Comment: actully i m facing warning  "Illegal offset type" due to square brackets in $test array keys...

Comment: Hi, kindly explain it more.

Comment: You need to remove the square brackets and parse it like I have described

Comment: yeah,thank you so much.i got it..thanks a lot every one

Answer (score 0):

welcome to PHP-MySQL world! ;)

I had problems with the name only-numeric of columns in database, but this example runs:

```
<?php 
///////// DATABASE CONECTION /////////

    // (host, user, password, database_name)
    $conection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database') or die('Connection failed');
    mysqli_set_charset($conection, 'utf8');

// your array
    // !!CAUTION: name columns in database only numeric maybe will give you problems later in SQL Sentences). KEY array name = column name
    $test= Array(
        "col0" => "1",
        "col2" => "22",
        "col4" => "1",
        "col5" => "0.25",
        "col6" => "0.25",
        "col8" => "1.25",
        "col9" => "0.25",
        "col11" => "1",
        "col29" => "0.25",
        "col30" => "0.25",
        "col32" => "0.25",
        "col33" => "0.25"
    );

    // array_keys() function returns an array containing the keys
    $columns = array_keys($test);
    // array_values() function returns an array containing all the values of an array
    $values = array_values($test);

// build your mysql sentetence:
    // $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (col0, col1) VALUES ('value0', 'value1')"
    // The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (" . implode(", ", $columns) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')";

// execute mysql sentence in database
    mysqli_query($conection, $sql) or die('Insert table1:'.mysqli_error($conection));

?>
```